# Auto hyperlinks inside article using given tags - Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am developing an article website, I have a list of 5-10 tags attached with each article.

Thing I am trying to achieve is if there is same exact word (from given tags) is used in article, it should hyperlinks to that tag/category.

For example tags are as following:

```
trading, financial, growth, imports, government
```

And article is like:

```
Government has put sanctions on imports from northern allies to stabilize its economy. This will support growth of GDP.
```

So according to my requirements `government, imports & growth` should be hyperlinked with `abc.com/tags/imports`.

How can I achieve this using laravel blade. Is their any package for that? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to put the links to the article **before** you pass it to blade. After you've pulled the data from database you can handle it with some method based on str_replace (or str_ireplace for case-insensitive) like this:

```
public function addTagLinks(string $text, array $tags): string
{
  $links = [];
  foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $links[] = '<a href=' .url(...) . '>'.$tag.'</a>';
  }
  return str_replace($tags, $links, $text);
}
```